# JS shortcut affect if superior

Tags: javascript

is there a way to minimize this type of code plz :

```js
position = newPosition > position ? newPosition : position;
```

This code is in a forEach. I'm pretty sur there's a way to achieve it but I can't remember...

Thanks all !

Comment: Are those numbers? You can use `Math.max(newPosition, position)`

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: "*This code is in a forEach*" - can you share the entire code, please? There are probably more opportunities to optimise/minimise the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already pretty short code, but here's a more efficient version, which avoids `position = position` assignment:

```js
if (newPosition > position) position = newPosition;
```

As @VLAZ mentioned in a comment, a more readable version would be to use `Math.max`, though this will be a bit slower as it involves a function call:

```js
position = Math.max(position, newPosition);
```

In case you care about performance, I ran [a quick benchmark](https://jsbench.me/vfkrdkbmka/1) for the case that `newPosition` is not greater than `position`. On Chrome on Windows at least, the `if` version came out a couple of percent faster than the `?` version, while the `Math.max` version came out about 20% slower than the `?` version.